# Word to describe gay people who are in a relationship with each other

Tags: phrase-requests, kinship-terms

Can I use these words?

> **A gay couple** (not sure if *couple* can be used only for married
>   people)
>
> **A gay lovers** (not sure if I should put *s* here or if *lovers* can be
>   used to describe two people who love each other)

Comment: *Lovers* is plural so you cannot use *A*. Simply *gay lovers* would do.

Comment: Why in the world would anyone ever say *They are gay lovers* or *He’s his gay lover* instead of the simple *They are lovers* or *He’s his lover*? Similarly for *couple*; the word alone suffices; you don’t need to qualify it with *gay*. Just say that *They’re a couple.* It seems, I don’t know, “something”-ist to me to qualify it.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, unless the couple being gay is central to the topic.  In that case using *gay couple* is fine.

Comment: Is it necessary to explicitly describe them as _homosexual_ lovers?  If not, you could just call them "lovers".

Comment: @tchrist I think the "something"-ist you're looking for might be heteronormativist, which totally does not exist as a real word (but heteronormative does)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say *they are a gay couple* or *they are gay lovers* to refer to two gays in love with each other and not necessarily married.

Comment: Or just "they are lovers".  Presumably the person you're speaking to has noticed that they are of the same gender.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming they're not legally married, gay and Lesbian couples usually refer to each other as "my partner" when speaking to others. If they are married, variations on *husband* and *wife* are used. Sometimes a gay relationship will have two husbands, two wives, or a husband and a wife.

If the relationship is less formal, *boyfriend* and *girlfriend* are often used.

I have no citation for this; it's just what I've heard and observed.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard *anyone* (gay OR straight) refer to "my lover" except ironically.  (Many people use it humorously, sometimes to refer to pets, children, or even celebrities.)  "Boyfriend", "girlfriend", "SO" (significant other) and "partner" are the variations I regularly hear when people are talking about their own actual relationships.

Comment: @MT_Head: I didn't use the term "lover" at all. If that's your complaint, take it up with Jasper above.

Comment: I didn't have a complaint at all - in fact I upvoted your answer.  That was actually a "yeah, I've seen the same thing and here's a bit of amplification" comment, rather than a "NOOO!  You're wrong!" comment.

Comment: I've only heard "my lover" used by one person--a woman referring to her husband. (I thought it was cute.) But you're right, it's not common.

Comment: @MT_Head I've certainly heard, and used, *lover* in times when "person I'm in a long-term relationship with, that involves sex" is relevant; which isn't that often. The people I hear it most often from are those who (with the consent of all parties) have more than one lover, or otherwise are outside of monogamous assumptions that *lover*, *partner*, *life-partner*, *boyfriend/girlfriend/spouse/husband/wife* are all synonymous in practice, as they are for some but not all.